# Cloning a repo at bitbucket.org

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm trying to clone a forked repo at bitbucket.org but I come up with this error:

```
error: RPC failed; result=
fatal: The remote end hung
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

I don't understand this error, those anyone has an idea of this error, and what should I do to avoid this error so my cloning succeed?

Comment: What is your Git version? your OS? The *full* result of `git clone --progress -v bitbucket/address /your:path` ?

Comment: What command did you execute?

Comment: git version 1.7.9.msysgit.0 and I'm using windows xp OS.
and I executed this command:
git clone https://xxx@bitbucket.org/username/repo.git

Comment: Does this happen every time? Does this also happen on other hosts, or only on Bitbucket? Have you contacted Bitbucket about this issue?

Comment: are you sure you're using the right repository address for clone?

Comment: yes sure i'm using the right repo

Comment: yes sure.
Are this errors had caused by slow internet connection?
    error: RPC failed; result=18, HTTP code = 200| 7 KiB/s
    fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
    fatal: early EOF
    fatal: index-pack failed

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with the same error message while cloning a repository that was 1.5 GB. I solved it by changing the way of cloning from [HTTPS to SSH](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=270827678). SSH worked.

The steps are intimidating but just take it a step at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps from this page:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=693897332